# Add all values in same class javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get the total value of all the values that have a class called total

```
<script>
function gettotal()
{

var total = 12;

}
</script>

<input type=text class=total value=5>
<input type=text class=total value=7>
<input type=submit  name=submit value="Add" onclick=gettotal();>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
var total = 0;
var totalElems = document.getElementsByClassName("total");
for (var i = 0; i < totalElems.length; i++) {
    total += parseInt(totalElems[i].value, 10);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a slight error. Shouldnt this line `total += parseInt(total[i].value, 10);` be `total += parseInt(totalElems[i].value, 10);`